# Migrate a solution from VS2015 to VS2022

Tags: types, output

I am attempting to migrate a project from Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, to Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11.  I experienced several errors mostly to do with file paths but one error has me stumped -- Upon attempting to build the solution, I get "Target Type 'appcontainerexe' is not supported by this task."  I see that that my file (project name).csproj file contains a line `<Output Type>AppContainerExe</Output Type>`.  I am not very sharp on this stuff (70 years old) so please keep any answers simple.  : )

I tried other output types and for example, 'winexe' gives the error "Output type 'Windows Application' is not supported by one or more of the project's targets.  I have tried so many different things that I can't describe them all, but all just lead to new errors.

Comment: What language and what type of application?  (Add that to the question text.) One option is to create a new project of the type that you want then just add in the code from the old one, that can be easier than looking through 100+ settings to find the one that didn't get upgraded automatically.  I just went through that changing a project from 32-bit to 64-bit.

Comment: When you say migrate.. what's your migration strategy? are you using any tools or utilities to upgrade?

Comment: The app was done in C# in Visual Studio 2015.  It is a vehicle maintenance tracking application.  When I say "migrate" I just mean update it to run in VS2022.  Not trying to change any functionality, just update it so that I can us VS2022 to make future changes.  I just took the VS2015 files and opened it with VS2022.  Thanks for your comments.  Please keep them coming.

Comment: For anyone it might benefit, I was able to resolve this issue.  I decided to take it one step at a time:  I copied the solution from my old windows 10 computer on which it successfully ran, copied it onto the new computer with Windows 11 operating system. Then opened it with Visual Studio 2015. After only one issue with the appxmanifest file, I was able to get it to run in VS2015 on the new computer.  Then I opened the same solution in Visual Studio 2022 and it successfully built and ran!  I hope this helps someone else with similar circumstances.

Comment: I found it easier to create a new project, and drag an drop all the CS files and folders in. Saved more time than googling Migration and trying to find the option in VS 2022.